# ManyToManyField relationship retrieving no data

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've one structure like this:
 1. Author
 2. Book
 3. AuthorType 
 4. AuthorBookType

A book can have more than one author, and it can have functions inside the book like: "Author", "Co-Author", "Part", "Helper", Etc:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Author(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    books=models.ManyToManyField(Book, through='AuthorBookType')


class AuthorType(models.Model):
    description=models.CharField(max_length=100)


class AuthorBookType(models.Model):
    author=models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book=models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author_type=models.ForeignKey(AuthorType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My database should look like this:

```
AUTHOR:
__________________________
| ID | NAME              |
|========================|
| 1  | Jhon Doe.         |
| 2  | Charles Albert    |
| 3  | Matt Greg         |
| 4  | Anne Engel        |
--------------------------

BOOK:
__________________________
| ID | NAME              |
|========================|
| 1  | Paradise City     |
| 2  | Profaned Apple    |
--------------------------

AUTHOR_TYPE:
__________________________
| ID | DESCRIPTION       |
|========================|
| 1  | Author            |
| 2  | Co-Author         |
--------------------------

AUTHOR_BOOK_TYPE:
_____________________________________________
| ID | AUTHOR_ID | BOOK_ID | AUTHOR_TYPE_ID |
|===========================================|
| 1  | 1         | 1       | 1              |
| 2  | 2         | 1       | 2              |
| 3  | 3         | 1       | 2              |
| 4  | 3         | 2       | 1              |
| 5  | 4         | 2       | 2              |
---------------------------------------------
```

On my views.py i did:

```
class AuthorsListView(ListView)
    model = Author
    context_object_name = 'authors'
    template_name = 'core/authors_list.html'
```

Then on my template just:

```
{% for author in authors %}
    {{ author.name }}<br>
    {{ author.books }}
{% endfor %}
```

The return was:

```
<author name>
<core.Books.None>
```

Did i anything wrong?
I searched for examples like this, but i found some old examples with Django 1.x, none for 2.x.

On documentation i found no examples like this (only without junction table).
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in the syntax between Django versions here; any of the docs you found would still work.

You need to iterate through the many-to-many relationship:

```
{% for author in authors %}
    {{ author.name }}<br>
    {% for book in author.books.all %}{{ book.title }}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more clear solution.

```
from .models import Author
class AuthorsListView(ListView)
    model = Author
    context_object_name = 'authors'
    template_name = 'core/authors_list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Author.objects.all()
```